# Extract Json data from a countries.csv file on github, and create a seperate array of timezones

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, parsing

[Country.csv](https://github.com/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database/blob/master/csv/countries.csv)

this is `countries.csv` file, and i want to extract all the timezones from it, which is its 14th colomn, and the data in there is not properly `json formatted`. I'm trying to parse the json but it failed. Actually, I want to create an `array` of timezones  like this

```php
    [0] => {zoneName:'Asia -> Kabul',gmtOffset:16200,gmtOffsetName:'UTC+04:30',abbreviation:'AFT',tzName:'Afghanistan Time'}
    [1] => {zoneName:'Europe -> Mariehamn',gmtOffset:7200,gmtOffsetName:'UTC+02:00',abbreviation:'EET',tzName:'Eastern European Time'}
    [2] => {zoneName:'Europe -> Tirane',gmtOffset:3600,gmtOffsetName:'UTC+01:00',abbreviation:'CET',tzName:'Central European Time'}
    [3] => {zoneName:'Africa -> Algiers',gmtOffset:3600,gmtOffsetName:'UTC+01:00',abbreviation:'CET',tzName:'Central European Time'}
    [4] => {zoneName:'Pacific -> Pago_Pago',gmtOffset:-39600,gmtOffsetName:'UTC-11:00',abbreviation:'SST',tzName:'Samoa Standard Time'}
    [5] => {zoneName:'Europe -> Andorra',gmtOffset:3600,gmtOffsetName:'UTC+01:00',abbreviation:'CET',tzName:'Central European Time'}
    [6] => {zoneName:'Africa -> Luanda',gmtOffset:3600,gmtOffsetName:'UTC+01:00',abbreviation:'WAT',tzName:'West Africa Time'}
```

what i'm doing, is this in `App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class` is this

```php
    public function timezone(): void {
        $data = [];

        if (($open = fopen(__DIR__ . '/countries.csv', 'r + b')) !== FALSE) {
            while (($singleRecord = fgetcsv($open, NULL, ',')) !== FALSE) {
                $data[] = $singleRecord;
            }
            fclose($open);
        }

        $data = $this->removeCharacters($data, ['[', ']']);
        $data = $this->removeCharacters($data, (array)'\/', " -> ");

        // $data = $this->removeCharacters($data, (array)'{}', '');
        // dd(explode('},', $data[33][14]));
        // dd(explode('},', $this->longJson));
        // dd(explode(',', str_replace(['{', '}'], '', $data[167][14])));

        $singleArray = [];
        $count = count($data);
        $itemsArray = [];

        for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {

            $singleArray[] = explode('},', $data[$i][14]);

            foreach ($singleArray as $item) {

                foreach ($item as $singleItem) {

                    $itemsArray[] = $singleItem;

                }
            }
        }
        $itemsArray = array_unique($itemsArray);

        $this->printFormattedData($itemsArray);
    }
 private function removeCharacters($hayStack, array $charsArray, $character = ''): array {
        $tempArray = [];
        foreach ($hayStack as $item) {
            $tempArray[] = str_replace($charsArray, $character, $item);
        }
        return $tempArray;
    }

    private function printFormattedData($data): void {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

Comment: maybe you go with json_decode to have an array with key all property?

Comment: `json_decode()` works only if the string contains `{` and `}` once, but i have big data, where somewhere single could have multiple starting and closing braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regexp its not perfect solution, but you can transform timezone data to correct json format using function like this:

```
public function fixJson(string $str): string {
    return preg_replace(
        '/(?<=(\{|\,))(\w+)(?=\:)/',
        '"$2"',
        str_replace("'", '"', $zoneRaw) // may not work properly, if values may contain apostroph symbols, but seems not actual for your case
    );
}
```

So, use this function:

```
$this->fixJson($data[$i][14]); // returns json string
json_decode($this->fixJson($data[$i][14])); // returns json decoded array
```

See usage example here https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/88f21

Comment: this solution worked for me, but for long lines like `{},{},{]` i had to ```php explode() ``` the string and making another `array` and `merging` both arrays

Answer (score 1):

Following code would do, what you aim.

`Please do not forget to mark this answer as ACCEPTED and thumbs up if it solves your problem, so that the work of the developers who help is appreciated and other developers can see in question list, that your question has already an accepted answer.`

```php
$lines = file("countries.csv");
array_shift($lines); // remove the first line with column names

$searchReplace  = ['\/' => '->'];
$search = array_keys($searchReplace);
$replace = array_values($searchReplace);

$jsonFormattedTimeZones = [];
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $line = trim(str_getcsv($line)[14], " []");
    $line = str_replace($search, $replace, $line);
    $jsonFormattedTimeZones[] = $line;
}

print_r($jsonFormattedTimeZones);
```

[image]

Comment: this approach is very good if the string is like `{}`

Comment: @Danish I took your statement `Actually,  I want to create an array of timezones like this` as basis for my solution. What do you mean with `if the string is like {}` ?

Comment: thanks for your effort and providing the solution to a beginner like me.
i think you have not checked the entire jsons inside of csv file, some jsons are like `{}` and some are very long like `{},{},{},{}.......`, and one `{}` denotes for one timezone, and some states and countries have multiple timezones. and I created a table with timezones where I'm storing all the timezones. 
I hope you are understanding me.

Comment: @DanishMehmood I see. :) As beginner it is always a little bit difficult to deal with the terminology. Every developer makes this experience. But if you be careful with the terminology, it would speed up your learning curve. In JSON `{}` is an object, `[]` is an array, `[{}]` is an array with only one object `[{}, {}, {}, ...]` is an array with multiple object. The last two examples are also called `object array` or `array of objects`. I really did no care about the object array in the countries.csv. :)